# childNodes object selector [not found] for Javascript File Upload widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload, widget

Looking to solve this childNodes object selector Javascript issue. Here is my querySelector function, and the pertinent childNodes  tags. I need to call a function based on a widget for file upload on the  & class="upload_content" id="jqxFileUpload". What am I missing on my $(document.querySelector() to select this childnode?

$(document.querySelector('.component__section, .holy-grail, .holy-grail__body, .jqxFileUpload)').jqxFileUpload({

```
<section class="component_section">
    <div class="data_page">
        <div class="data_page_body">
            <div class="data_content">
                <div class="upload_content" id="jqxFileUpload">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have an ID, just use "#jqxFileUpload" as your selector (`$("#jqxFileUpload")`)

Comment: when I tried: I received an error 'Uncaught TypeError' on this like: $("#jqxFileUpload")({
            theme: 'summer',
            browseTemplate: 'success',
            uploadTemplate: 'primary',
            cancelTemplate: 'warning',
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            fileInputName: 'fileToUpload',
         width: 300, 
         uploadUrl: 'file_upload.py'
        });